# Elasticsearch - join two different types of documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these documents:

**mymovies**

```
{
    "_index": "mymovies",
    "_type": "mymovie",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
     "title" : "Funny title is here"
     "genre" : "Comedy"
     "movieViews" : 901142
    }
}


 {
        "_index": "mymovies",
        "_type": "mymovie",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         "title" : "Sad title is here"
         "genre" : "Drama"
         "movieViews" : 90
        }
 }

 {
        "_index": "mymovies",
        "_type": "mymovie",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         "title" : "Sad Second title is here"
         "genre" : "Drama"
         "movieViews" : 9022
        }
 }

 {
        "_index": "mymovies",
        "_type": "mymovie",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         "title" : "Horror title is here"
         "genre" : "Horror"
         "movieViews" : 9022
        }
 }
```

**user**

```
{
  "Name" : "Doni de brun",
  "moviesLiked": [2,1,3]      
}
```

1. How do I get only genres that a specific user liked ?
2. Is there a better way to organize the data for this query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following query will do the job:

```
POST movies/_search
{
  "size": 0

  , "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [2,1,3]
    }
  }

  , "aggs": {
    "genres_for_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "genre",
        "size": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your document structure looks good.

Make sure you have [not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) index for genre field. If you keep default analyzer for this field, values like "Classic comedy" will be indexed as two keywords, and in aggregation query will generate two counters, for *classic* and *comedy*.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no easy way to join queries in Elasticsearch. But you can keep your data nested like:

```
{
    "Name" : "Doni de brun",
    "moviesLiked": [
        {    
            "title" : "Horror title is here",
            "genre" : "Horror",
            "movieViews" : 9022 
        },
        {  
            "title" : "Sad title is here",
            "genre" : "Drama",
            "movieViews" : 90
        }
    ]      
}
```

The downside of that is you need to duplicate your data. But you can easily do the searches you want by using nested queries:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html

Comment: if I'm orgnize data in that way - a movie will appear multiple times in data. moreover, when updating a movie I will need to search all of its occurrences.

Comment: Yes, thats true. But with accepted answer you are just searching regularly. It has nothing to do with joining documents.

Comment: you right.. I've made some confusion with "join" term.